# Executing an MS Access macro from a scheduled task when the file is security file protected?

Tags: security, ms-access, batch-file, windows-server-2003, ms-access-2003

We have a series of Scheduled Tasks that run batch files that run MS Access macros on a Windows Server 2003 machine at work.

The batch files run with a command like so:

```
%PATH_TO_MS_ACCESS% C:\UCPData\SomeTaskDb.mdb /wrkgrp "C:\UCPData\Security.mdw" /x Macro1
```

The Task Scheduler `Status` reads `The scheduled task did not run because an incorrect password or user name was entered`.

When I right click the task in `Scheduled Tasks` and `Run` the task nothing happens.

But when I run the batch file from the `run` dialog it runs just fine.  So it isn't a password issue.

The task is run as administrator.  Is there some other reason the task won't run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The issue was that the administrator password changed on the network but not in each of the individual Scheduled Tasks.